# Add number to each object in 2d array

Tags: java

These objects all have an attribute thats called number, i want to now add to every object in this 2d array a number, starting from 0 to 99.

So tiles[0][0] has the number 0 and tiles[9][9] has number 99. tiles[3][0] should have number 2.

I tried putting this in a nested for loop like this:

```
for(int x = 0; x < mapWidth; x++)
        {
            for(int y = 0; y < mapHeight; y++)
            {
                for(int i = 0; i <100; i++){                        
                tiles[x][y].nummer(i);                    
                }
            }    
        }
```

but with this the nummer is always 99? it isnt 0 to 99

How can i do this in a for loop or something?

SO MY QUESTION IS:
how can i make it so that the nummer for the tiles goes from 0 to 99?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: What's the logic behind what number a tile gets? Why `tile[3][0]` has `2`?

Comment: @Maljam oh thats wrong it should be 4, well i could explain it as its tiles[x][y] and tiles[3][0] is the 4th tiles from the top left, so thats why its 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int counter = 0;
for(int y = 0; y < mapHeight; y++)
        {
            for(int x = 0; x < mapWidth; x++)
            {                      
                tiles[x][y].number(counter);
                counter++;                    
            }    
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

it's because you are running a loop that sets the number from `0` to `99` on *every* tile, so you end up with `99` everywhere.

Instead you should do something like:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < 100 ; i++) {
        tiles[i%10][i/10] = i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also just use a variable to keep the counter

```
int num = 0;
for (int y = 0; y < mapHeight; y++) {
 for (int x = 0; x < mapWidth; x++) {
  tiles[x][y].nummer(num);
  num++;
 }
}
```